# serialport.on reads multiple times of same data read in meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, serial-port

in myproject is  Meteor Js framework backend with node js
,serialport communication to read and write input and outputs.This below code run in the *setIntervel*.Each intervel has code run and result produced.
`serialPort.write("adc read 0 \r");
                serialPort.on('data', function(Result) {
                    var analog = Result.toString().split("\n");
                    var index = analog[0].substring(9);
                    var analogData = analog[1];
                    console.log('index: '+index+'result: '+analogData);
 });`
The above console is print multiple times.

The **OUTPUT** is

> interval 1

Index:0 result:776

> interval 2
>
> Index:0 result:778
>
> Index:0 result:778

Then increase intervel times..1,2,3,5,7  order....
How to Prevent this Increment?